# Glasses not following the head

Tags: rigging

Hey I don't know if this is a rigging problem but when I move my model in pose mode, the glasses (which are hovering over the face but connected to the whole mesh) doesn't move with the head. How do I fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if the glasses have weight painting on them. They should be red when the head is red (when the head bone is selected).

Comment: perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: When in pose mode, select glasses, then Shift+select the Head bone (becomes light blue), then hit Ctrl+P, Bone. This will parent the glasses to the head bone directly.